# How to batch convert web pages to pdf programmatically?

Tags: batch-file, pdf, pdf-generation, programmatically-created

I have quite large number of `URLs` in form of `some/web/address/[0-9]+` and want to convert all of them to `PDF`, How can I do that?

I've Googled and searched over stackoverflow for it but if it is a duplicate give me a link to a good question and I would delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for:

I needed something like `wkhtmltopdf` as it can change `HTML` files to `PDF`.
there's also a good command-line browser `cURL` that can catch web pages and has a rich feature set.
So I can pipe these two and get my desired result:

```
for i in `seq 1 n`; do
    curl "some/web/address/$i" "prefix-$i.html";
    wkhtmltopdf "prefix-$i.html" "prefix-$i.pdf"
done;
```

**`Happy coding :)`**